# Stay on page and don't reset form fields when Javascript alert in php

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I am having troubles with a form in php and some Javascript code embedded in it.

I would like to stay on the page and don't reset the form fields after a Javascript alert. When the alert is shown, the page reloads and all the fields in the form are reset.

Here is the code:

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['captcha'])) {
if (empty($_SESSION['captcha']) || trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['captcha'])) != $_SESSION['captcha']) {

      echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

      alert(\"El texto no coincide, por favor vuelva a intentarlo\");

      return false;

      </script>"; 


} else {

     $para = 'xxx';
     $asunto = 'Mensaje de mi sitio xxx';
     $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
     $email = $_GET['email'];
     $contenido = "Mensaje enviado por " . $nombre . " \r\n";
     $contenido .= "e-mail es: " . $email . " \r\n";
     $contenido .= "Mensaje: " . $_GET['texto'] . " \r\n";
     mail($para, $asunto, $contenido);
     echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">

     alert(\"Gracias por contactar con nosotros, nos pondremos en contacto lo antes posible.\");
     document.contacto.captcha.select();
     return false;

     </script>"; 

}
$request_captcha = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['captcha']);

unset($_SESSION['captcha']);

}
```

Thanks so much in advance for your help.

Have a great day.

Comment: Your code shows nothing of a reload. Where are you doing that?

Comment: It would make more sense to parse the submission on submit() with JS and prevent the default submit behavior unless the form validates.

Comment: Also, email header injection vulnerabilites are present: http://www.nyphp.org/phundamentals/8_Preventing-Email-Header-Injection

Answer (score 0):

Is your form posting to this php? I presume you've trimmed the form HTML out of your question. If you want to validate the form this way, you'll need to fill in values in the form HTML based on $_REQUEST.

A better solution would be to validate the form using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code should grab the data on the $_POST request, and send it back to the page after reload.
Then, the inside the form, you should check for each variable, and if its not empty, prepopulate the fields on the form.

This is time consumin for you as a developer if you are not using a framework (as the code suggest).
Try one of the most popular ones, that make an excelent work handling forms and validations for you like Symfony2, Laravel, Zend Framework2.